# How to connect my Swift app to my Parse Server?

Tags: objective-c, swift, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm working on connecting my Parse app to my Node.js Parse Server with the Swift language. In the documentation of Parse, I can see this code :

```
[Parse initializeWithConfiguration:[ParseClientConfiguration configurationWithBlock:^(id<ParseMutableClientConfiguration> configuration) {
   ...

   configuration.applicationId = @"YOUR_APP_ID";
   configuration.clientKey = @"YOUR_APP_CLIENT_KEY";
   configuration.server = @"http://localhost:1337/parse";

   ...

}]];
```

And since I use the Swift language, here is my configuration until now :

```
// Initialize Parse.
Parse.setApplicationId("APP_ID", clientKey: "CLIENT_KEY")
```

But how can I specify the server as in the Objective-C code ?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI - Parse.com is shutting down. You should find another solution before finishing your app.

Comment: @rmaddy That is exactly why I am trying to migrate to a Parse "self-hosted" Server ;-)

Comment: Ah. Perhaps there needs to be a new tag for that.

Comment: @rmaddy exactly, that's what I think too. 
Btw, I found the answer to this question by myself and will post the solution now.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Found the answer by myself, here is how to set a configuration (including the server URL) with Swift :

```
let parseConfiguration = ParseClientConfiguration(block: { (ParseMutableClientConfiguration) -> Void in
    ParseMutableClientConfiguration.applicationId = "APP_ID"
    ParseMutableClientConfiguration.clientKey = "CLIENT_KEY"
    ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server = "http://your_server.com:1337/parse"
})

Parse.initializeWithConfiguration(parseConfiguration)
```

Hope it will help someone else.

Answer (score 3):

Parse Server now has some good [documentation](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Parse-Server-Guide) going and it basically recommends @fraxool's solution with a little neater syntax:

```
let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration {
    $0.applicationId = "YOUR_APP_ID"
    $0.clientKey = ""
    $0.server = "http://localhost:1337/parse"
}
Parse.initializeWithConfiguration(configuration)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add the answer with Swift 3:

```
   let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration {
        $0.applicationId = "YOUR_APP_ID"
        $0.clientKey = ""
        $0.server = "http://localhost:1337/parse"
    }
    Parse.initialize(with: configuration)
```

Answer (score -1):

// Set App ID

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration {
            $0.applicationId = PARSE_APP_KEY
            $0.clientKey = PARSE_CLIENT_KEY
            $0.server = "https://example.com"
        }
          Parse.initialize(with: configuration)

   return true
}
```

Comment: Parse.initialize(with: configuration) missing